# Connection between forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm programming in c# Express 2010, and I have many forms in the program. I want one form be able to see the variables and methods in another form such as Form 8 can see and use the methods defined in form 5, should I define an object of type form 5 in form 8? how does  a form can see variables in another form in c#?

Thanks

Comment: You should give your forms better names than “form 5”.

Comment: In fact, she'll *have* to, since spaces won't work.

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things here:

1) As @Yuck suggested, creating a class that will contain the members you need to share between those two forms, and pass an instance of that class when creating a new instance of a Form (in the constructor, or through a property, etc)

2) Create a *static* class that will have the required fields in such a place where both forms have access, and then you will be able to do:

```
Information.Field1
Information.Field2
Information.Method1()
```

supposing the class is `Information` and some properties are `Field1`, `Field2` and a method `Method1()`.

Of course, the second option isn't always possible, because it could depend on non-static fields, etc.

**Edit:**
Another thing to consider is to pass that object within an event. You can create an event in one of the forms, and suscribe to it in the other form.

Of course, that will depend on what exactly you need to do, but those 3 are valid options to share an object between two forms.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with the shared values you need, then pass instances of that class between the forms as a constructor argument.  I can't create a code sample as you didn't mention what data elements are required.

Comment: You can even pass the parent form as a parameter to a child form constructor, copy that arg to a child form variable (for instance, called "parentForm"), and then access the (public) variables and messages from the parentForm.

Comment: An even easier (although not necessarily better) way is to just use the overloads of `Show` and `ShowDialog` that take an `Owner` parameter (pass `this` as the owner). Then, to reference the parent form from the child form, you cast the child form's `Owner` property to `Form1` (or whatever the parent form's type is).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't sound like a very good design.  For the purpose of your question, you can pass an instance of form1 to form2 via a constructor when instantiating form2, and then form2 will have access to all of form1's public fields.  Tell us a little more about what you are trying to do, there is probably a better way without having to pass around instances of your forms and their data.

Comment: Thanks! I have a program that calculate risk for something, so I have questions in form1 and others in form2 and I want to add the results of the answers of the questions to be shown in text box in form2, sometimes form2 need to use methods in form1, any help?

Comment: Create a separate static class which stores the answers to the questions of all of the forms.  This way you are separating the data storage from your user interface, and any class that needs to access it only needs to reference the static class where you store the data.  Other users have already suggested this here as an answer, and it looks to be the best solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Application.OpenForms` to get all open forms in your application
then by iterating over it like

```
  foreach (var frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Form2))
            {
                (frm as Form2).Method1();
            }

        }
```

You can access each form and by casting it original type you can use public variable and methods of this form.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a new class to hold the shared (global) values. You can simply define those values as properties of whatever form they are in (with appropriate getters and setters) and refer to them as SomeFormOrAnother.ThisProperty. This is slightly better than simply making the form variables themselves public.

Mind you, for a complex application this is likely not the best design, but for something relatively simple it's quick and effective.

Comment: Hmmm.. if he has Form1 and Form2, and he want to show Form2 and use some properties from Form1... how is he supposed to do that? I mean, he will have to pass the Form1 instance to Form2, or in some way refer from Form2 to their parent (in case it was shown using `ShowDialog()` or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to handle communication between forms.  Since you describe this as a questionaire of sorts, I'm going to assume that the second form is one which you're showing modally (meaning you can't click the form underneath while it's open), on which you collect some functionally related stuff and add it all up to display in a simpler format back on your main form.

Assuming you're showing the second form from a button click, put code like this in the button click method:

```
using (ChildForm child = new ChildForm())
{
    child.ShowDialog(this); // the "this" is important, since it lets 
                            // the child reference the parent form in 
                            // a simple way

    // the code here will block (or stop) on the above line until the user
    // closes the form. Then you can still reference the child's properties,
    // even though it's no longer visible.
    string something = child.something;
}
```

To make the child form's `something` property visible, you declare it as `public` in the child form, like so:

```
public string something = String.Empty;
```

According to many, this is wrong - you should make `something` accesible like this:

```
private string _something = String.Empty;
public string something
{
    get
    {
        return _something;
    }
}
```

I'll leave that debate to others.  In your child form, whenever you need to refer back to a method in the parent form (you have to make any such method `public`), you do it like this:

```
ParentForm parent = (ParentForm)this.Owner;
int someValueOrOther = parent.callSomePublicMethod();
```